# Drag & Drop files to Pygame and save them

Tags: python, file, pygame

I wonder if someone know anyway to make function to drag and drop image to pygame screen and after that save it to files in computer.
For example like in Photoshop.
or at least browse button like here:

[image]

I would like to use that image after that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Pygame seems to have limited support for dragging and dropping event, but it is possible to acomplish certain tasks.

It turns out that dropping a file on an active Pygame window will generate an event of type `pygame.DROPFILE` with a single `file` attribute which contains the absolute path to the file as  a string.

So, simple actions should be straightforward to implement from that.

The limitations are that, while *dragging* a file to be dropped on a pygame window, no event is generated whasoever: your program won't "know" that the user is carrying a file, they might just as well be stating at the screen with both hands in the air. So your program can not, using only pygame, procide any feedback on hot regions to drop the file, or show a thumbnail representing the file type while it is being dragged: you know nothing, not even the mouse position that, for ordinary mouse motion, generates a `pygame.MOUSEMOTION` event.

What happens is that as the file is *released* on the pygame window, 4 events are generated at once: (1) one single `pygame.MOUSEMOTION` event, with the coordinates where the file was dropped. The `pos` attribute contains the x, y position as usual, and the `rel` parameter is always `(0, 0)`, but this event is otherwise undistinguishable from an ordinary MouseMotion event, except by the events immediately following it.
(2) One pygame.DROPBEGIN event with no attributes
(3) One pygame.DROPFILE event with the `.file` attribute
(4) One pygame.DROPCOMPLETE event with no attributes

So you have to save the MOUSEMOTION  events, and whenever you get a "DROPFILE" , check the last MOUSEMOTION  received to determine its position.

I used this simple snippet on the interactive mode to figure all of this out:

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

def blah():
   for e in pygame.event.get():
       print e
   pygame.display.flip()

while True:
   blah()
   pygame.time.delay(100)
```